# Difference between Test Script Recorder in JMeter and BlazeMeter

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter

I am new to JMeter, I would like to know the difference between using Test Script Recorder in JMeter and BlazeMeter for recording test. Which is the most preferred one for testing a website?

Comment: if you want it simple, you can try [SmartMeter Recorder](https://www.smartmeter.io/quick-guide#toc-how-to-record-test-script).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) is provided OOTB by Apache JMeter and works with JMeter. It acts as a proxy between your browser and the server and intercepts traffic to create Samplers.

BlazeMeter is a commercial 3rd party SAAS that offers a tool called **[Proxy Recorder technology](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420545-BlazeMeter-Proxy-Recorder-Mobile-and-web-)** that also intercepts your traffic and creates the test plan. It does not require a local JMeter running for creating it. This means that all traffic of your application goes to their servers, this might be a security concern for you.

It is up to you to decide which one to use. But I would advise you to learn to use JMeter Test Script Recorder as once you master it you will really master Test Script creation, correlation and variabilization:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html

Answer (score 0):

Recording a test scenario has nothing in common with the web application load testing. The whole idea of the [Load Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_testing) concept is simulating the **antipicated** load to see how does application behave, what are the response times/throughput, do they match expectations, etc.

So the end goal is to mimic your application **real usage** and you won't be able to achieve this using record-and-replay capabilities of any load testing tool. BlazeMeter's solution should help you to build test scenario "skeleton" faster as in this case you won't have to deal with proxies, certificates, correlation, etc. Also BlazeMeter's solution will automatically add [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager), [HTTP Cache Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager), embedded resources handling applied to samplers and so on therefore you will be able to replay the test with increased number of users and it [will behave more like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser).

So it absolutely doesn't matter where and how did you get the script: recorded it using this or that option, created it manually by adding [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers, or hire someone to develop this for you. It is not even 10% of the activities connected with the load testing, the actual fun begins when you have executed your test and have results.